# How to use api in lambda python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, post, aws-lambda

I tried to log in into a website using post requests in python by passing the username and password using the below code and it worked.

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as c:
    url='http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login?mode=login'
    usr='admin'
    pwd='12345'
    c.get(url)
    print(c.cookies)
    login_data=dict(usr=usr,pwd=pwd)
    res=c.post(url,data=login_data)
    print(res)
    page=c.get('http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login?mode=welcome')
    print(page.content)
```

Now,I want to try the same(log in to the same website using post requests) in lambda aws in python.I am a beginner to lambda,aws and have no idea how to proceed in lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the code to run in lambda environment.

For that you will need a **lambda handler function** as described here:

- [AWS Lambda function handler in Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html)

Also `requests` is not provided anymore in lambda. Thus, the **easiest way to add** `requests` to your lambda function would be through lambda layers as described in section `Using AWS Lambda Layers` of:

- [Upcoming changes to the Python SDK in AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/upcoming-changes-to-the-python-sdk-in-aws-lambda/)

The crude version of your code for lambda would be (assuming `requests` layer is setup):

```
import requests

def handler(event, context):

    with requests.Session() as c:
        url='http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login?mode=login'
        usr='admin'
        pwd='12345'
        c.get(url)
        print(c.cookies)
        login_data=dict(usr=usr,pwd=pwd)
        res=c.post(url,data=login_data)
        print(res)
        page=c.get('http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login?mode=welcome')
        print(page.content)
```

Comment: Should I use any json.loads () while modifying the code?I just read some of the articles and they used json.loads and also urllib3.Thats  why I am a bit confused.

Comment: @lakshmi I added an example code. If you don't want to use `requests` layer than you can use python's build in tools for http functionality.